# Forward Apache ssl port 443 to Tomcat http port

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat8, proxypass

I have my tomcat running as standalone in my linux box on port 7778. I have configured apache to run on ssl on port 443.

My httpd.conf is as below:

```
    Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost> -->
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:7778/website
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:7778/website
```

My ssl.conf is as below:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/certificate/file
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
</VirtualHost>
```

My server.xml connector is as below:

```
<Connector port="7778" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                proxyName="www.domain.com" proxyPort="80" />
```

Issue is my Apache is not able to redirect to Tomcat on 7778 port and gives 503 error.

Comment: Why can't you just use 443 on the app?

Comment: try moving the ProxyPass directives inside the VirtualHost

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

**1** Firts confirm your Tomcat is ok.

Make sure you can connect to http://localhost:7778/website and get the expected response.

Then, for proxy support modify your Connector:

```
<Connector port="7778" protocol="HTTP/1.1" proxyName="www.example.com" proxyPort="80" />
```

**2** Fix your Apache configuration

Here I assume:

- when you try http://www.example.com you are redirected to https://www.example.com
- when you try https://www.example.com you get the response from Tomcat

  ```
  Listen 80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.example.com
      ServerAlias example.com

      CustomLog "logs/80_access.log" combined
      ErrorLog  "logs/80_error.log"

      Redirect / https://www.example.com
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName www.example.com
      ServerAlias example.com

      # While debugging
      LogLevel debug
      CustomLog "logs/443_access.log" combined
      ErrorLog  "logs/443_error.log"

      SSLEngine On
      SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/certificate/file
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key

      # Proxy to Tomcat
      ProxyRequests Off
      ProxyPass        / http://localhost:7778/website
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7778/website

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

**What you may have to adjust**

- Log files directory
- certificate files directory
- LogLevel, remove debug mode once it works
- Make sure required modules are loaded.  `apachectl -t` will let you know if you are missing any.